# How to Plot Fourier Transform of cos(2x) correctly with Numpy and Python

Tags: python, numpy

I watch a video about Fourier Transform and in the Fourier Transform plot of the funciton `cos(2x)` the hike should be at `ω=-2` and `ω=2`, but why mine is different:

[image: myplot]

[image: therealplot]

this is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.fftpack

# Number of samplepoints
N = 600
t = np.arange(0.0, 20.0, 0.1)
# sample spacing
T = -1.0 / 1.0
x = np.linspace(0.0, N*T, N)
yt = np.cos(2.0*t)
y = np.cos(2.0*x)
yf = scipy.fftpack.fft(y)
xf = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*T), N//2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(14, 7))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)

ax1.plot(xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[:N//2]))
ax1.set_title("$FT\{f(x)\}$")

ax2.plot(t,yt)
ax2.set_title("$f(x) = cos(2x)$")
ax2.set_xticks([0, np.pi, 2 * np.pi])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Unrelated: `plt.subplots` already creates axes for you. `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=...)` and then no need to `add_subplot`

Comment: Yes, I did not know that it is more efficient to write `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=...)` alone. I only follow codes I have found and modify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ω`, the angular frequency, can be defined as `ω = 2πf`. You're plotting in terms of frequency, not angular frequency.

To get the peak where you're expecting it, simply change your plotting instructions to:

```
ax1.plot(2*np.pi*xf, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf[:N//2]))
```